# Non-trivial Extensions of Sheaves of $\mathcal{O}$-Modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I am working on Problem XI.4. E of Miranda’s book “Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces”.

> Let $X=\mathbb{P}^1, p = \infty, \mathcal{O}[n]=\mathcal{O}[n\cdot p]$. Write down a nontrivial extension of $\mathcal{O}[0]$ by $\mathcal{O}[-2]$.

Here’s my (wrong) solution:

By Riemann-Roch theorem, 
$\dim H^1(-2\cdot p)=1$, thus a nontrivial extension exists.

Denote $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}[-2], \mathcal{G}=\mathcal{O}[0]$, let $\{U_i\}$ be an open cover of $X$ on which $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ both trivialize. Assume on $U_i$, the local automorphism is given by 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & b_i \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
where $b_i\in\mathcal{O}(U_i)$.

In particular, choose $U_1=X\setminus\{\infty\}, U_2=X\setminus\{0\}$ and let $z, w$ be local coordinates on $U_1, U_2$ respectively.  Then a local generator of $\mathcal{F}$ can be given by 
$f_1(z)=1$ on $U_1$ and $f_2(w)=w^2$ on $U_2$. A local generator of $\mathcal{G}$ can be given by $g_1=g_2=1$.

The transition functions are
$t_{12}=f_1/f_2=1/w^2$ and $s_{12}=1$.
Now according to page 363, we know $\{b_i\}$ should satisfy the compatibility condition, i.e., 
$b_i=s_{ij}b_j/t_{ij}$. In our problem, that is, 
$b_1(z)=w^2b_2(w)$.
However, I don’t think there are $b_i\in\mathcal{O}(U_i)$ which can satisfy this equation.

Could you help me spot what’s wrong in my solution? Many thanks!

Comment: What if one considers $b_1 = 1$ and $b_2(w) = 1/w^2$?

Comment: @random123 I think $b_2(w)$ should be holomorphic in $U_2$?

Comment: And it is. The point 0 is not in the open set $U_2$.

Comment: @random123 This is a part which confuses me. Since $w$ is the local coordinate around $\infty$, $w$ actually takes $0$ at $\infty$ I suppose?

Comment: I see. You are correct.

Comment: I think the transition functions are wrong. The $t_{12}$ should come out to be $1/w^2$. The cartier divisor corresponding to  $-2p$ is given by $1$ and $1/w^2$ in the local coordinates. Hence the line bundle has $1/(1/w^2) = w^2$ as its transition function. I hope I am not wrong.